# Write BigDecimal calculation as if it's just a usual Four arithmetic operations in Scala

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, bigint

I'm currently working on Scala and getting surprised how good it is.
One of the great points I think is how it handles `BigDecimal` type.Once defining a `BigDecimal` You can use it almost as if it is `Int` or `Double`

```
val foo:BigDecimal = 0.1
println(foo + 0.2) // 0.3
```

There is no need to use `.multiply()` or `.add()` but simply `+` or `*` to handle BigDecimal Calculation(I assume `BigDecimal`'s `+`/`*` end up calling them inside of it though).It's really easy to read even if a calculation gets complicated EXCEPT one thing that You have to declare first calculated value as `BigDecimal`.

```
println(0.3 * (BigDecimal(0.1) + 0.2))
```

My question is, How Can I write above code like this?

```
println(0.3 * (0.1 + 0.2))
```

I assume that this requires to override numeric type literals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can override numeric literals. What you can do is simplify the syntax a bit using string interpolation or adding methods to `Double`.

```
// With string interpolation
implicit class BigDecimalStringContext(private val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def d(args: Any*): BigDecimal = {
    val stringRepr = sc.s(args: _*)
    BigDecimal(stringRepr)
  }
}

println(d"0.3" * (d"0.1" + d"0.2"))
println(0.3 * (d"0.1" + 0.2))


// Pimp my library 
implicit class DoubleOps(private val d: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def bd = BigDecimal(d)
}

println(0.3.bd * (0.1.bd + 0.2.bd))
println(0.3 * (0.1.bd + 0.2))
```

The first method is safer, because the second one tries to convert a `Double`, and thus may lose precision:

```
scala> 0.123456789012345678901234567890.bd * (0.1.bd + 0.2.bd)
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.037037036703703704

scala> d"0.123456789012345678901234567890" * (d"0.1" + d"0.2")
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.0370370367037037036703703703670
```

Comment: I agree with the "Pimp my library" approach you've shown. You could even write it as `println(0.3 bd * (0.1 bd + 0.2 bd))` which might be nicer to read, subjectively.

Answer (score 2):

Scala doesn't allow overriding literals, unfortunately.

One thing you could easily do from within the language proper, would be to provide your own [`StringContext`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.StringContext) for [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

```
implicit class BigDecimalStringContext(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def d() = BigDecimal(sc.parts.head)
}

val test = d"0.1"
// => test: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.1
```

I believe [Macros](http://scalamacros.org/) don't allow you to override literals.

[Scala-Virtualized](https://github.com/tiarkrompf/scala-virtualized) is a fork of Scala, where (almost) everything (including control structures and object construction) translates into a method call and can thus be overloaded. Unfortunately, *almost* everything does not include overloading literals.

You might, however, be able to do something with a Compiler Plugin.